# Linux building external module headers path problem

Tags: android, build, linux-kernel

I'm trying to compile a linux [kernel module](https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/la/platform/vendor/qcom-opensource/wlan/qcacld-2.0/commit/?id=b5112838eb91b71eded4b5ee37338535784e0aef), but now
I'm stuck with error:

```
In file included from <command-line>:0:0: 
/lineage/kernel/xiaomi/msm8996/include/linux/kconfig.h:4:32: fatal error: generated/autoconf.h: No such file or directory 
#include <generated/autoconf.h>
```

BTW, I can successfully build the kernel, and I also find .config file under `/lineage/out/target/product/gemini/obj/KERNEL_OBJ`

How should I fix this error?

Here is full log:

```
$:/lineage$ make -j4 -C kernel/xiaomi/msm8996 M=../../../vendor/qcom/opensource/wlan/qcacld-2.0 O=../../..//lineage/out/target/product/gemini/obj/KERNEL_OBJ ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPIL
E=arm-eabi- modules WLAN_ROOT=../../../vendor/qcom/opensource/wlan/qcacld-2.0 MODNAME=wlan BOARD_PLATFORM=msm8996 CONFIG_QCA_CLD_WLAN=m WLAN_OPEN_SOURCE=1 
make: Entering directory '/lineage/kernel/xiaomi/msm8996' 
make[1]: Entering directory '/lineage/lineage/out/target/product/gemini/obj/KERNEL_OBJ' 

 ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid. 
        include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing. 
        Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it. 


 WARNING: Symbol version dump ./Module.symvers 
          is missing; modules will have no dependencies and modversions. 

 CC [M]  ../../../vendor/qcom/opensource/wlan/qcacld-2.0/CORE/HDD/src/wlan_hdd_assoc.o 
 CC [M]  ../../../vendor/qcom/opensource/wlan/qcacld-2.0/CORE/HDD/src/wlan_hdd_cfg.o 
 CC [M]  ../../../vendor/qcom/opensource/wlan/qcacld-2.0/CORE/HDD/src/wlan_hdd_debugfs.o 
 CC [M]  ../../../vendor/qcom/opensource/wlan/qcacld-2.0/CORE/HDD/src/wlan_hdd_dev_pwr.o 
In file included from <command-line>:0:0: 
/lineage/kernel/xiaomi/msm8996/include/linux/kconfig.h:4:32: fatal error: generated/autoconf.h: No such file or directory 
#include <generated/autoconf.h> 
                               ^ 
In file included from <command-line>:0:0: 
/lineage/kernel/xiaomi/msm8996/include/linux/kconfig.h:4:32: fatal error: generated/autoconf.h: No such file or directory 
#include <generated/autoconf.h> 
                               ^ 
In file included from <command-line>:0:0: 
/lineage/kernel/xiaomi/msm8996/include/linux/kconfig.h:4:32: fatal error: generated/autoconf.h: No such file or directory 
#include <generated/autoconf.h> 
                               ^ 
compilation terminated. 
compilation terminated. 
compilation terminated. 
/lineage/kernel/xiaomi/msm8996/scripts/Makefile.build:257: recipe for target '../../../vendor/qcom/opensource/wlan/qcacld-2.0/CORE/HDD/src/wlan_hdd_assoc.o' failed 
make[2]: *** [../../../vendor/qcom/opensource/wlan/qcacld-2.0/CORE/HDD/src/wlan_hdd_assoc.o] Error 1 
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs.... 
/lineage/kernel/xiaomi/msm8996/scripts/Makefile.build:257: recipe for target '../../../vendor/qcom/opensource/wlan/qcacld-2.0/CORE/HDD/src/wlan_hdd_dev_pwr.o' failed 
make[2]: *** [../../../vendor/qcom/opensource/wlan/qcacld-2.0/CORE/HDD/src/wlan_hdd_dev_pwr.o] Error 1 
In file included from <command-line>:0:0: 
/lineage/kernel/xiaomi/msm8996/include/linux/kconfig.h:4:32: fatal error: generated/autoconf.h: No such file or directory 
#include <generated/autoconf.h> 
                               ^ 
compilation terminated. 
/lineage/kernel/xiaomi/msm8996/scripts/Makefile.build:257: recipe for target '../../../vendor/qcom/opensource/wlan/qcacld-2.0/CORE/HDD/src/wlan_hdd_cfg.o' failed 
make[2]: *** [../../../vendor/qcom/opensource/wlan/qcacld-2.0/CORE/HDD/src/wlan_hdd_cfg.o] Error 1 
/lineage/kernel/xiaomi/msm8996/scripts/Makefile.build:257: recipe for target '../../../vendor/qcom/opensource/wlan/qcacld-2.0/CORE/HDD/src/wlan_hdd_debugfs.o' failed 
make[2]: *** [../../../vendor/qcom/opensource/wlan/qcacld-2.0/CORE/HDD/src/wlan_hdd_debugfs.o] Error 1 
/lineage/kernel/xiaomi/msm8996/Makefile:1386: recipe for target '_module_../../../vendor/qcom/opensource/wlan/qcacld-2.0' failed 
make[1]: *** [_module_../../../vendor/qcom/opensource/wlan/qcacld-2.0] Error 2 
make[1]: Leaving directory '/lineage/lineage/out/target/product/gemini/obj/KERNEL_OBJ' 
Makefile:145: recipe for target 'sub-make' failed 
make: *** [sub-make] Error 2 
make: Leaving directory '/lineage/kernel/xiaomi/msm8996' 

#### make failed to build some targets (2 seconds) ####
```

Comment: Kernel needs to be configured first before you compile. You need to have `.config` generated. You can use `defconfig` or `menuconfig` to create your configurations. Try, `make -f Makefile help` for all the options.

Comment: I have .config generated under /lineage/out/target/product/gemini/obj/KERNEL_OBJ directory.

Comment: @DzmitrySankouski  Have you fixed it?   I also come to a similar situation like yours now.